# Branch differently in x86 / x86-64 using only printable visible ASCII characters in the machine code

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source, machine-code, x86-family

The task is simple: write a program that branches differently in x86 (32-bit) and x86-64 (64-bit) using only printable visible ASCII characters 0x21...0x7e (space and del are not allowed) in the machine code.

- Conditional assembly is not allowed.
- Using API calls in not allowed.
- Using kernel-mode (ring 0) code is not allowed.
- The code must run without causing exceptions in both IA-32 and x86-64 in Linux or in some other protected mode OS.
- The functioning must not depend on command line parameters.
- All instructions must be encoded in machine code using only ASCII characters in the range 0x21...0x7e (33...126 decimal). So eg. `cpuid` is out of limits (it's `0f a2`), unless you use self-modifying code.
- The same binary code must run in x86 and x86-64, but as file headers (ELF/ELF64/etc.) may be different, you may need to assemble and link it again. However, the binary code must not change.
- Solutions should work on all processors between i386...Core i7, but I'm interested also in more limited solutions.
- The code must branch in 32-bit x86 but not in x86-64, or vice versa, but using conditional jumps is not a requirement (indirect jump or call is also accepted). The branch target address must be such that there is space for some code, at least 2 bytes of space in which a short jump (`jmp rel8`) fits in.

The winning answer is the one that uses least bytes in the machine code. The bytes in the file header (ELF/ELF64 for example) are not counted, and any bytes of code after the branch (for testing purposes etc.) aren't counted neither.

Please present your answer as ASCII, as hexadecimal bytes and as commented code.

My solution, 39 bytes:

ASCII: `fhotfhatfhitfhutfhotfhatfhitfhut_H3<$t!`

hexadecimal: `66 68 6F 74  66 68 61 74 66 68 69 74  66 68 75 74 66 68 6F 74  66 68 61 74 66 68 69 74  66 68 75 74 5F 48 33 3C 24 74 21`.

Code:

```
; can be compiled eg. with yasm.
; yasm & ld:
; yasm -f elf64 -m amd64 -g dwarf2 x86_x86_64_branch.asm -o x86_x86_64_branch.o; ld x86_x86_64_branch.o -o x86_x86_64_branch
; yasm & gcc:
; yasm -f elf64 -m amd64 -g dwarf2 x86_x86_64_branch.asm -o x86_x86_64_branch.o; gcc -o x86_x86_64_branch x86_x86_64_branch.o

section .text
global main
extern printf

main:
    push    word 0x746f     ; 66 68 6f 74 (x86, x86-64)
    push    word 0x7461     ; 66 68 61 74 (x86, x86-64)
    push    word 0x7469     ; 66 68 69 74 (x86, x86-64)
    push    word 0x7475     ; 66 68 75 74 (x86, x86-64)

    push    word 0x746f     ; 66 68 6f 74 (x86, x86-64)
    push    word 0x7461     ; 66 68 61 74 (x86, x86-64)
    push    word 0x7469     ; 66 68 69 74 (x86, x86-64)
    push    word 0x7475     ; 66 68 75 74 (x86, x86-64)

    db      0x5f            ; x86:    pop edi
                            ; x86-64: pop rdi

    db      0x48, 0x33, 0x3c, 0x24
                            ; x86:
                            ; 48          dec eax
                            ; 33 3c 24    xor edi,[esp]

                            ; x86-64:
                            ; 48 33 3c 24 xor rdi,[rsp]

    jz      @bits_64        ; 0x74 0x21
                            ; branch only if running in 64-bit mode.

; the code golf part ends here, 39 bytes so far.

; the rest is for testing only, and does not affect the answer.

    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop

    jmp     @bits_32

@bits_64:
    db      0x55                    ; push rbp

    db      0x48, 0x89, 0xe5        ; mov rbp,rsp
    db      0x48, 0x8d, 0x3c, 0x25  ; lea rdi,
    dd      printf_msg              ; [printf_msg]
    xor     eax,eax
    mov     esi,64

    call    printf
    db      0x5d                    ; pop rbp

    NR_exit equ 60

    xor     edi,edi
    mov     eax,NR_exit     ; number of syscall (60)
    syscall

@bits_32:
    lea     edi,[printf_msg]
    mov     esi,32
    call    printf

    mov     eax,NR_exit
    int     0x80

section .data

printf_msg: db "running in %d-bit system", 0x0a, 0
```

Comment: You really hit the hot hat in the hut :)

Comment: Nice. Odd, but nice. Since you are setting the winning condition as "shortest" I'm going to change the tag to [code-golf] and add a some new descriptive tags. If you don't like them, let me know.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## 7 bytes

```
0000000: 6641 2521 2173 21                        fA%!!s!
```

As 32 bit

```
00000000  6641              inc cx
00000002  2521217321        and eax,0x21732121
```

As 64 bit

```
00000000  6641252121        and ax,0x2121
00000005  7321              jnc 0x28
```

`and` clears the carry flag so the 64 bit version always jumps. For 64-bit the `6641` is the operand size override followed by `rex.b` so the operand size for the `and` comes out as 16 bit. On 32-bit the `6641` is a complete instruction so the `and` has no prefix and has a 32-bit operand size. This changes the number of immediate bytes consumed by the `and` giving two bytes of instructions that are only executed in 64-bit mode.

Comment: Congrats on reaching 1k.

Comment: this behaviour is CPU specific.  Some 64-bit systems will ignore the 66 prefix in 64-bit mode.

Comment: @peterferrie Do you have a reference for that? My reading is that a 66h prefix is ignored when REX.W is set but this only has REX.B

Comment: excuse me, I'm wrong.  It's only transfer-of-control that's affected that way (e.g. 66 e8 doesn't switch to 16-bit IP on Intel).

Answer (score 7):

### 11 bytes

```
ascii: j6Xj3AX,3t!
hex: 6a 36 58 6a 33 41 58 2c 33 74 21
```

Uses the fact that in 32-bit, 0x41 is just `inc %ecx`, whereas in 64-bit it is the `rax` prefix that modifies the target register of the following `pop` instruction.

```
        .globl _check64
_check64:
        .byte   0x6a, 0x36      # push $0x36
        .byte   0x58            # pop %rax
        .byte   0x6a, 0x33      # push $0x33

        # this is either "inc %ecx; pop %eax" in 32-bit, or "pop %r8" in 64-bit.
        # so in 32-bit it sets eax to 0x33, in 64-bit it leaves rax unchanged at 0x36.
        .byte   0x41            # 32: "inc %ecx", 64: "rax prefix"
        .byte   0x58            # 32: "pop %eax", 64: "pop %r8"

        .byte   0x2c, 0x33      # sub $0x33,%al
        .byte   0x74, 0x21      # je (branches if 32 bit)

        mov     $1,%eax
        ret

        nop
        nop
        nop
        nop
        nop
        nop
        nop
        nop
        nop
        nop
        nop
        nop
        nop
        nop
        nop
        nop
        nop
        nop
        nop
        nop
        nop
        nop
        nop
        nop
        nop
        nop
        nop
        mov     $0,%eax
        ret
```

Wrote this on OSX, your assembler might be different.

Call it with this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern int check64(void);
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (check64()) {
    printf("64-bit\n");
  } else {
    printf("32-bit\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

### 7 bytes

Not relying on 66 prefix.

```
$$@$Au!
```

32-bit:

```
00000000 24 24 and al,24h
00000002 40    inc eax
00000003 24 41 and al,41h
00000005 75 21 jne 00000028h
```

AL will have bit 0 set after the INC, the second AND will preserve it, the branch will be taken.

64-bit:

```
00000000 24 24    and al,24h
00000002 40 24 41 and al,41h
00000005 75 21    jne 00000028h
```

AL will have bit 0 clear after the first AND, the branch will not be taken.

Answer (score 0):

If only C9h were printable...

32-bit:

```
00000000 33 C9 xor  ecx, ecx
00000002 63 C9 arpl ecx, ecx
00000004 74 21 je   00000027h
```

The ARPL will clear the Z flag, causing the branch to be taken.

64-bit:

```
00000000 33 C9 xor    ecx, ecx
00000002 63 C9 movsxd ecx, ecx
00000004 74 21 je     00000027h
```

The XOR will set the Z flag, the MOVSXD will not change it, the branch will not be taken.

Comment: If not for the printable-characters restriction, 5 byte is possible.  [x86-32 / x86-64 polyglot machine-code fragment that detects 64bit mode at run-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38063529). `xor eax,eax` / db 0x40 (REX or inc eax) / `jz .64bit_mode`.  `xor eax,eax` is `31 C0`, but the branch displacement could be chosen to be printable.

Comment: If we had a known initial state for FLAGS (PF=0), `push 'b'` / `pop eax`/rax ; db 0x40 / `jne .64bit_mode` works (6 bytes).  But with an extra dec or inc to make sure PF has known state in 64-bit mode, it's 7 bytes.  Unfortunately `or al, imm8` has an opcode outside the ASCII range, and any ModRM with register operands will have its high bit set.